# Pass input to sqlite IN operator (Javascript, Cordova)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I am using sqlite in cordova environment for iPad. While querying a select statement with single input, I do something like this

```
tx.executeSql("select * from activityData_table where id=? ;", [outage.outageId], function(tx, res)
```

But what if I want to select using a IN operator as given below.

```
select * from activityData_table where id in (val1,val2,val2)
```

How will I form the query and pass inputs to it. Will a array of values suffice or do we need to manually do any concat operations?

I couldn't find any documentations for using sqlite with JS. If any one could suggest a documentation or a tutorial site for reference will be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the count of the values and then generate the statement like this (pseudo code):

```
var values = [1,2,3,4];

var count = values.length;

var sql = 'select * from activityData_table where id in (';

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if(i != (count - 1)) {
        sql += '?,';
    }
    else {
        sql += '?)';
    }
}

tx.executeSql(sql,values);
```

Comment: Yes. I thought about this. But I want the code to be cleaner. Thats why hesitating to use this.

Comment: A true case of bikeshedding